# How do you improve your Kavvanah [concentration]?

Tags: tefilla, how-to, kavana-concentration

Building on my blog post [here](http://rechovot.blogspot.com/2010/06/how-do-you-improve-your-kavvanah.html), I ask: How do you improve your concentration when davening?

Comment: See also: http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/190/experience-based-advice-for-focusing-and-slowing-down-prayers . I'd love to see some more techniques listed.

Answer (score 9):

A few ideas that help me:

- Be the shaliach tzibbur.  Your mind requires more focus and this spills over into kavana.
- Although many say it is praiseworthy to stand during chazaras hashatz and krias hatorah, I find that sitting helps me follow along better.  Do not try to do this if you took my previous advice of being the shaliach tzibbur!
- I have a gemara seder before davening.  By the time davening starts, my mind is psyched and focused.
- Another idea which I should do more often than I do is stop davening when I notice a space out.  I find it is much easier then to transition to a focused state than to do so while davening.

Comment: Make it an avodah to try and pronounce each word correctly according to whichever tradition of pronounciation you follow. The sheer mechanics of clear, concise, and correct pronounciation will automatically slow you down and force you into a whole new level of attention. Of course, if you're davenen in a minyan you may have to skip some parts since most minyanim go too fast to allow for correct pronounciation.

Comment: @Shemmy, that could be an answer.

Comment: @Shemmy Make it an answer!

Comment: *Administrative note: This answer was given to another question and merged hither.*

Answer (score 7):

I find that singing parts help.

Comment: YRU, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks for contributing your experience! I look forward to seeing you around.

Comment: I think this point is underestimated! To take out parts, especially, first beracha in Shmoneh Esreh, to a nice, slow niggun, and sing it, alone, to myself, is a whole different experience! Everyone should now about this wonderful advice!

Answer (score 6):

Following the exact question "How do you improve your concentration when *davening*?" I would suggest that the main effort at improvement of *kavanah* should be done **before** *davening*.

1. Learning *be'ur t'fillah* and eventually learning *seforim* that teach the inner dimensions of the words we use in *t'fillah* is important.
2. Spending time before *davening* to gather your thoughts and feelings and to quiet the outside "noise" of one's own thoughts is an ancient technique that was used by the *hasidim harishonim*, the early pious Jews.

Answer (score 5):

1. Take a minute to clear your mind and try to fee the presence of Hashem all around you.
2. Daven to Hashem to help you daven with *Kavanah*
3. Every time you catch your mind straying, ask for Hashem's help again
4. Keep reminding yourself that Hashem and all the Heavenly hosts are counting on you.
5. Keep your fingers on the place.
6. Learn the meaning of what you are saying
7. Say only one phrase at a time.
8. *Daven* aloud and if you are able try singing the words.
9. Invest each *Bracha* in *Shmoneh Esrai* with personal details
10. Specify your indebtedness to Hashem,embellish your praise and detail your requests
11. Try to daven near those who pray with Kavanah

This is very basic summary, and additional answers to those already provided. (From: Ezras Nashim)

Comment: The Alter Rebbe writes in the siddur that at minimum a person should have the Kavanah that Hashem should hear his prayers and that all the kavanos should aid in its ascent.

Answer (score 5):

I rarely lacked concentration when reading something in English.  When I have, it has easily come back by reading the same passage over again. The only thing I can think of, is that you actually understand and make sure you translate each word you say into your mind.  When I have done that during davening, I have also never lacked conentration. The hard part for me, is to do that during davening, since I often feel "rushed"

In those times, I tell myself a synopsis of the bracha/paragraph I'm reading, and then read quickly.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest **trying** not to think of anything other than the the actual meanings of the words - sometimes thinking about other things distracts you and makes you forget

Comment: lyb, welcome to Judaism.SE, and thanks very much for this answer! Please consider registering your account, which will give you access to more of the site's features, including the ability to respond to other people's posts with comments like this one.

Comment: The introduction for the Siddur HaGra (Ishei Yisroel / Siach Yitzchok) seemingly contradicts this suggestion. He says that it is much easier to concentrate on a general, overall topic in the prayer than to פירוש המילים.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps pictures pertaining to the particulars of each *b'racha* could help! Someone has compiled a chart of such pictures [here](http://www.hakhel.info/archivesPublicService/KavanahImagery.pdf), but I imagine one could compile one's own. I have never tried this, but multiple modalities often produce multiple (and therefore stronger) associations to concepts, which could improve concentration.

Answer (score 4):

A technique I used to employ, but which I only advise if you have a lot of time to Daven, was to pause during each Berachah in Shemoneh 'Esreh and think of at least one example that would apply to that particular Berachah.

Comment: This is reminiscent of Ramba"n's advice in his famous _igeres_ pertaining to learning Torah. He recommends finding a way that each bit of learning applies to one's own life right after learning it.

Answer (score 1):

Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chayim 93:2-3

> You shouldn't stand to pray [in any manner] except with fear and
>   trepidation; not after making fun or lightheadedness or idle talk, and
>   not after anger. Rather, after the joy [of a mitzvah (M"B)]. ... We
>   don't stand to pray after judgment or after halachah so that his heart
>   shouldn't be upset by it [i.e. still working on it]; rather after
>   decided halachah. Hagah [Rama]: And this is also considered after joy ...

Comment: *Administrative note: This answer was given to another question and merged hither.*

Answer (score 1):

Pray with the devotion and simplicity of a child, with your finger on each and every word that you say from the siddur.

If we walk into shul with the notion that G-d "opens His Hand and satisfies the desire of every living being," we see that our prayers will be answered.

In shul, we are in a dialogue with Hashem - we speak to Him directly. Knowing that you are able to converse with the most perfect being in existence, who is attentively listening to each word you say, may keep you interested.

Each prayer we say, in any context, is one G-d hears.

Comment: *Administrative note: This answer was given to another question and merged hither.*

Answer (score 1):

Ideas that help (and I still need improvement in this area)

1. Contemplate relationship to H' during walk to shul. Simply saying over and over 'H' is in control' has helped me.
2. Stop shuckling
3. Read the tefilla in a conversational cadence
4. Pick one and take as long as you need to read it and appreciate it in English
5. If you find a phrase that resonates to you- perhpas is a bracha you want, underline it and you will find you read it with kavanah most days. (my latest one is in the birkas haTorah- Vehaarev na ... Make the words of Torah sweet in our mouths...)

Comment: Why "stop shuckling"?  I find it *improves* my kavanah...