# How can I stop spacing out during davening?

Tags: tefilla, kavana-concentration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you improve your Kavvanah [concentration]?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1780/how-do-you-improve-your-kavvanah-concentration)

Any suggestions for improving concentration or advice on how to avoid daydreaming during tefilah?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/190/experience-based-advice-for-focusing-and-slowing-down-prayers Possible duplicate: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1780/how-do-you-improve-your-kavvanah-concentration