# How can we have better Kavanah in Tefilla? Specifically Tachnuneem?

Tags: tefilla, tachanun, kavana-concentration

How does one have better Kavanah in his Tachnuneem tefilla? Does he punch his chest harder? Maybe start bawling?

Comment: I would suggest focusing on the meaning of the words, as opposed to inflicting physical pain.

Comment: Chest punching and/or bawling may or may not be effects of better Kavanah, but they aren't causes of it.

Comment: Duplicate of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26698 + http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/190?

Comment: @Fred I was just joking relax everybody.

Answer (score 1):

By learning the  Chayei Odom at the ending of Klall 143 where he elaborates on each word of Oshamnu etc.