Personal Bakashot in Shema Koleinu or Elokai
When we speak to Hashem in our own words and make our personal bakashot, is it more proper to say this in Shema Koleinu (right before כי אתה שומע) or do we say it in Elokai Nezur (after the paragraph but before the second Yihiyu Lerazon)?
Does it matter what type of bakasha you’re making? For instance, some siddurim have set texts in Shema Koleinu for Parnassah and forgiveness, while the text of Elokai seems to be about thoughts and enemies.

I think the question can be extended and you could also add: Could it be that because it is better to say Kedusha with a minyan, one should shorten requests in the middle brachos and leave most of the requests to Elokai Netzor?

@YDJ yess that’s exactly why I have this question!

The rules about adding to the normal text are found in OC 119. In short, personal requests that fit thematically with a particular blessing (eg. forgiveness, health, livelihood, in blessings 6,8,9 respectively) are added to their particular blessing, and any requests that don't fit elsewhere go in blessing 16 (שמע קולינו). After prayer-proper comes "Tachanun" which has no fixed form and you can add whatever supplications you want (such as for a fast day).
There is a minority opinion of Rabbenu Yonah that the Shulchan Aruch recommends following if you can as a nice stringency (cf. Beit Yosef and Aruch Hashulchan ibid.) that additional personal requests must be phrased in the singular and additional communal requests must be phrased in the plural, and some say (MA ibid.) that this applies to שמע קולינו as well. Some also say (ibid. :2) that additional personal requests can't be "too long". Additionally, while prayer can in principle be in any language (OC 101:4) there is some dispute about the language requirements of individual additions, especially if mixing languages with the regular text being in Hebrew.
Accordingly, if you want to not deal with any of that then just stick all your additions after prayer in whatever wording/language you want. However, please acknowledge the religious cost that comes with that, whereby your "prayer" isn't where you actually pray to God.

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/47675/759
